# Compile 32 bit application on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, cfs

I am trying to build NASA cFS version 6.5 which uses 32bit applications on a 64 bit Jetson TX2 running Ubuntu.

I was getting the error `"gcc: error: unrecognized command line option -m32"`.

I tried installing the `gcc-multilib` but I get:

`Package gcc-multilib is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`

I tried looking for other packages using `apt search gcc-multilib` and I installed:
`gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi`
`gcc-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf`
`gcc-multilib-x86-64-linux-gnu`
`gcc-multilib-x86-64-linux-gnux32`

I know there's ones I probably don't need to install but I looked everywhere for a solution and couldn't find any.

I tried uncommenting all the lines in the `sources.list`, running `sudo apt-get update` and then and then trying to install but still no success.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

Okay so I removed the -m32 option from the cmake files that have it and tried to compile and I  got a whole bunch of errors ranging from typedef erorrs to missing ; and others, not gonna list all of them because they're probably over 100 errors, but the first error I get is:
`/home/deployer/CFS-101.initial/osal/src/os/inc/common_types.h:285:5: error: #error undefined processor`

So I went the common_types.h and this is what it contains:

```
#ifndef _common_types_
#define _common_types_

#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif

/*
** Includes
*/

/*
** Macro Definitions
*/

/* 
** Condition = TRUE is ok, Condition = FALSE is error 
*/
#define CompileTimeAssert(Condition, Message) typedef char Message[(Condition) ? 1 : -1]


/*
** Define compiler specific macros
** The __extension__ compiler pragma is required
** for the uint64 type using GCC with the ANSI C90 standard.
** Other macros can go in here as needed, for example alignment 
** pragmas.
**
** NOTE: The white-box (coverage) unit testing may need to disable
** these extra attributes.  These test builds define the OSAPI_NO_SPECIAL_ATTRIBS
** macro to disable this.
*/
#if defined (__GNUC__) && !defined(OSAPI_NO_SPECIAL_ATTRIBS)
   #define _EXTENSION_     __extension__
   #define OS_PACK         __attribute__ ((packed))
   #define OS_ALIGN(n)     __attribute__((aligned(n)))
   #define OS_USED         __attribute__((used))
   #define OS_PRINTF(n,m)  __attribute__ ((format (printf, n, m)))
#else
   #define _EXTENSION_ 
   #define OS_PACK
   #define OS_ALIGN(n) 
   #define OS_USED 
   #define OS_PRINTF(n,m)
#endif

/*
 * If the host system has a ISO C99 standard stdint header file, prefer it.
 * This ensures that fixed-width types are correct including on 64-bit systems.
 */
#if defined(_HAVE_STDINT_)

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
/*
 * NOTE - NOT DEFINING STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST or STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST
 * We should not make assumptions about the bit order here
 */

  typedef uint8_t                               osalbool;
  typedef int8_t                                int8;
  typedef int16_t                               int16;
  typedef int32_t                               int32;
  typedef int64_t                               int64;
  typedef uint8_t                               uint8;
  typedef uint16_t                              uint16;
  typedef uint32_t                              uint32;
  typedef uint64_t                              uint64;
  typedef intptr_t                              intptr;
  typedef uintptr_t                             cpuaddr;
  typedef size_t                                cpusize;
  typedef ptrdiff_t                             cpudiff;

/*
 * Fall back to default integer type maps -
 * These definitions assume a 32-bit processor
 */
#elif defined(_ix86_) || defined (__i386__)
/* ----------------------- Intel x86 processor family -------------------------*/
  /* Little endian */
  #undef   _STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST_
  #define  _STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST_

  typedef unsigned char                         osalbool;
  typedef signed char                           int8;
  typedef short int                             int16;
  typedef long int                              int32;
 _EXTENSION_ typedef long long int              int64; 
  typedef unsigned char                         uint8;
  typedef unsigned short int                    uint16;
  typedef unsigned long int                     uint32;
  _EXTENSION_ typedef unsigned long long int    uint64;

  typedef unsigned long int                     cpuaddr;
  typedef unsigned long int                     cpusize;
  typedef long int                              cpudiff;

#elif defined (_ix64_) || defined (__x86_64__) 
/* ----------------------- Intel/AMD x64 processor family -------------------------*/
  /* Little endian */
  #undef   _STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST_
  #define  _STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST_

  typedef unsigned char                         osalbool;
  typedef signed char                           int8;
  typedef short int                             int16;
  typedef int                                   int32;
  typedef long int                              int64;
  typedef unsigned char                         uint8;
  typedef unsigned short int                    uint16;
  typedef unsigned int                          uint32;
  typedef unsigned long int                     uint64;

  typedef unsigned long int                     cpuaddr;
  typedef unsigned long int                     cpusize;
  typedef long int                              cpudiff;

#elif defined(__PPC__) || defined (__ppc__)
   /* ----------------------- Motorola Power PC family ---------------------------*/
   /* The PPC can be programmed to be big or little endian, we assume native */
   /* Big endian */
   #define _STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST_
   #undef  _STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST_

   typedef unsigned char                        osalbool;
   typedef signed char                          int8;
   typedef short int                            int16;
   typedef long int                             int32;
   _EXTENSION_ typedef long long int            int64;
   typedef unsigned char                        uint8;
   typedef unsigned short int                   uint16;
   typedef unsigned long int                    uint32;
   _EXTENSION_ typedef unsigned long long int   uint64;

   typedef unsigned long int                     cpuaddr;
   typedef unsigned long int                     cpusize;
   typedef long int                              cpudiff;

#elif defined(_m68k_) || defined(__m68k__)
   /* ----------------------- Motorola m68k/Coldfire family ---------------------------*/
   /* Big endian */
   #define _STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST_
   #undef  _STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST_

   typedef unsigned char                        osalbool;
   typedef signed char                          int8;
   typedef short int                            int16;
   typedef long int                             int32;
   _EXTENSION_ typedef long long int            int64;
   typedef unsigned char                        uint8;
   typedef unsigned short int                   uint16;
   typedef unsigned long int                    uint32;
   _EXTENSION_ typedef unsigned long long int   uint64;

   typedef unsigned long int                     cpuaddr;
   typedef unsigned long int                     cpusize;
   typedef long int                              cpudiff;

#elif defined (__ARM__) || defined(__arm__)
/* ----------------------- ARM processor family -------------------------*/
  /* Little endian */
  #undef   _STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST_
  #define  _STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST_

  typedef unsigned char                         osalbool;
  typedef signed char                           int8;
  typedef short int                             int16;
  typedef long int                              int32;
  _EXTENSION_ typedef long long int             int64;
  typedef unsigned char                         uint8;
  typedef unsigned short int                    uint16;
  typedef unsigned long int                     uint32;
  _EXTENSION_ typedef unsigned long long int    uint64;

  typedef unsigned long int                     cpuaddr;
  typedef unsigned long int                     cpusize;
  typedef long int                              cpudiff;

#elif defined(__SPARC__) || defined (_sparc_)
   /* ----------------------- SPARC/LEON family ---------------------------*/
   /* SPARC Big endian */
   #define _STRUCT_HIGH_BIT_FIRST_
   #undef  _STRUCT_LOW_BIT_FIRST_

   typedef unsigned char                        osalbool;
   typedef signed char                          int8;
   typedef short int                            int16;
   typedef long int                             int32;
   _EXTENSION_ typedef long long int            int64;
   typedef unsigned char                        uint8;
   typedef unsigned short int                   uint16;
   typedef unsigned long int                    uint32;
   _EXTENSION_ typedef unsigned long long int   uint64;

   typedef unsigned long int                     cpuaddr;
   typedef unsigned long int                     cpusize;
   typedef long int                              cpudiff;

#else  /* not any of the above */
   #error undefined processor
#endif  /* processor types */

/*
 * Boolean type for compatibility --
 *
 * Note it is a bad idea to typedef "bool" or "boolean" -- MANY other projects
 * and libraries also define a boolean type due to the lack of a standard bool in C89.
 * But calling it simply "bool" or "boolean" almost guarantees a namespace conflict
 * if trying to use OSAL with one of those other existing projects.
 *
 * RTEMS 4.11 no longer defines boolean type by default (deprecated) probably also
 * due to the high likelihood of name conflicts.
 *
 * In order to preserve compatibility for apps written against prior versions of
 * OSAL, the name "boolean" is typedefed as well, but this may be turned off
 * in a future version whenever appropriate.
 */

#if (!defined(_USING_RTEMS_INCLUDES_) || !defined(RTEMS_DEPRECATED_TYPES))
  typedef osalbool boolean;
#endif


#ifndef NULL              /* pointer to nothing */
   #define NULL ((void *) 0)
#endif

#ifndef TRUE              /* Boolean true */
   #define TRUE (1)
#endif

#ifndef FALSE              /* Boolean false */
   #define FALSE (0)
#endif

/* 
** Check Sizes 
*/
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(uint8)==1,  TypeUint8WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(uint16)==2, TypeUint16WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(uint32)==4, TypeUint32WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(uint64)==8, TypeUint64WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(int8)==1,   Typeint8WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(int16)==2,  Typeint16WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(int32)==4,  Typeint32WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(int64)==8,  Typeint64WrongSize);
CompileTimeAssert(sizeof(cpuaddr) >= sizeof(void *),  TypePtrWrongSize);

/*
 * TEMPORARY COMPATIBILITY MACRO
 *
 * Any code that depends on this macro should be fixed so as to not need it.
 * The value for this had been set by the BSP makefiles but this is not reliable,
 * especially on processors that support both big- and little- endian modes e.g.
 * ARM and MIPS.
 *
 * This is deprecated and only here to bridge the gap until code that depends
 * on this can be fixed.  Do not write any new code that uses this macro.
 *
 * If using an older makefile that defines one of the BIT_ORDER macros already,
 * then this entire section is skipped and the macro is used as-is.
 */
#if !defined(SOFTWARE_BIG_BIT_ORDER) && !defined(SOFTWARE_LITTLE_BIT_ORDER)

#if defined(__BYTE_ORDER) && __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN || \
    defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__) || \
    defined(__ARMEB__) || \
    defined(__THUMBEB__) || \
    defined(__AARCH64EB__) || \
    defined(_MIBSEB) || defined(__MIBSEB) || defined(__MIBSEB__)
/* It is a big-endian target architecture */
#define SOFTWARE_BIG_BIT_ORDER
#elif defined(__BYTE_ORDER) && __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN || \
    defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__) || \
    defined(__ARMEL__) || \
    defined(__THUMBEL__) || \
    defined(__AARCH64EL__) || \
    defined(_MIPSEL) || defined(__MIPSEL) || defined(__MIPSEL__)
/* It is a little-endian target architecture */
#define SOFTWARE_LITTLE_BIT_ORDER
#endif

#endif /* !defined(SOFTWARE_BIG_BIT_ORDER) && !defined(SOFTWARE_LITTLE_BIT_ORDER) */

#ifdef __cplusplus
   }
#endif

#endif  /* _common_types_ */
```

I tried checking if I have stdint.h and stddef.h and it turned out yes but I don't know why *HAVE_STDINT* isn't defined anywhere. Also, there is no case that checks for **aarch64** which is my machine, so I changed

```
#if defined(_HAVE_STDINT_)
```

to

```
#if defined(_HAVE_STDINT_) || defined(__arch64__)
```

I tried compiling and it compiled most of the tools but then I got this error:

```
Source file 'to_config.o' contains objects of class type 'ELFCLASS64 (2)' which is unsupported by this utility
```

I'm guessing this error is happening because I removed the -m32 flag for the elf2cfetbl tool.

Any help?

Comment: The gcc docs don't mention `-m32` for ARM. You should probably fix the broken build system files that cause gcc to be invoked with a flag that is invalid for your target.

Comment: I tried to remove the -m32 flag from the build files but some of these tools fail to build when I do so. It gives me many errors in the source code. I tried building the CFS on an ubuntu VM with gcc-multilib installed and it worked so the codes aren't the problem. What can I do in this case?

Comment: The `-m32` flag only applies on certain platforms, see [gcc options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html), so it's not surprising that it works on your Ubuntu VM (presumably x86-64) but not your ARM machine.  You're going to have to explain what those "many errors" are if you want help fixing them.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: The usual way to get 32-bit code on arm is to use `-march=armv7` or some other 32-bit architecture variant.  I would try just replacing `-m32` with `-march=armv7` and see what happens.